# How to work with wxString, numbers and other string types in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, string, wxwidgets

As I startded programming in C++ with wxWidgets (in code::blocks), I often had the issue that I did not know how to use wxString in a good way. The main reason was that there are already several string types in C++ and wxWidgets now adds another. I already had some classes imported from another project without wxWidgets, so now everything needed to be compatible.

This lead to several questions:

- How to convert wxString to another string type?
- How to convert another string type to wxString?
- How to convert an integer number to wxString?
- How to convert a wxString to an integer number?
- How to convert a floating point number to wxString?
- How to convert a wxString to a floating point number?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, there is [this helpfull site in the wxWidgets wiki](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Converting_everything_to_and_from_wxString) on how to deal with wxStrings. I will partly quote it, though in my opinion it is not as detailed as I would have needed it, this is why I created this Q&A.

---

## How to convert wxString to another string type?

For C style strings, I use this method:

```
wxString fileName = "myFile";
const char* fileNameChar = fileName.mb_str();
```

To convert wxString to std::string use (as the website says):

> wxWidgets 2.8 :
>
> ```
> wxString mystring(wxT("HelloWorld"));
> std::string stlstring = std::string(mystring.mb_str());
> ```
>
> Under wxWidgets 3.0, you may use
>
> ```
> wxString::ToStdString()
> ```

And for std::wstring under wxWidgets 3.0, you may use

```
wxString myString = "abc";
std::wstring myWString = wxString::ToStdWstring(myString);
```

(not tested, documented [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_string.html#acd4ba44e34428aa83cd9922d2933d060)).

---

## How to convert from another string type?

To convert from C style strings use:

```
const char* fileNameChar = "myFile";
wxString fileName(fileNameChar);
```

For std::strings either

```
std::string fileNameStd = "myFile";
wxString fileName(fileNameStd.c_str());
```

or (from wxWidgets 3.0)

```
wxString fileName(fileNameStd);
```

And for std::wstring:

> Starting from wxWidgets 3.0, you may use the appropriate constructor
>
> ```
> std::wstring stlstring = L"Hello world";
> // assuming your string is encoded as the current locale encoding (wxConvLibc)
> wxString mystring(stlstring);
> ```

---

## How to convert an integer number to wxString?

You can either use

```
int number = 3;
wxString myString = wxString::Format(wxT("%i"), number);
```

or

```
#include <wx/numformatter.h>

int number = 3;
wxString myString = wxNumberFormatter::ToString(number);
```

The second method is documented [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_number_formatter.html#abf3e465bc68a79821b00387271386fd3). You don't have to use the flag and you can use not only `long` as it is in the documentation, but other integer types as well (as I did here with `int`).

---

## How to convert wxString to an integer number?

I always use this method:

```
wxString numberString = "12345";
int number = wxAtoi(numberString);
```

---

## How to convert a floating point number to wxString?

You can use the first method if you don't need to set the accurracy of your floating point values (normal accurracy is 6 numbers after the comma)

```
double doubleNumber = 12.3455;
wxString numberString = wxString::Format(wxT("%f"), doubleNumber);
```

Be carefull, as it is `"%f"` no matter if you want to convert a `double` or a `float` number. If you try to use `"%d"` instead your program will crash. If you use this method to convert anything that has more than 6 digits after the comma, it will be cut.

If you need a given accurracy, you can use this function

```
#include <wx/numformatter.h>

double doubleNumber = 12.2345912375;
int accurracy = 10;
wxString numberString = wxNumberFormatter::ToString(doubleNumber, accurracy);
```

---

## How to convert a wxString to a floating point number?

> ```
> wxString number(wxT("3.14159"));
> double value;
> if(!number.ToDouble(&value)){ /* error! */ }
> ```

so the string number is written to `value`.

---

I hope this is helpfull to someone, as everytime I wanted to convert something I started searching the web again. If there are improvements to make or I forgot something, feel free to correct me, as this is my first Q&A :)

Answer (score 0):

All these questions and many more are answered in the wxWidgets wiki

https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Converting_everything_to_and_from_wxString

Comment: As you might see, I linked this in the answer. Also, there are things missing like `wxString myString = wxNumberFormatter::ToString(number);`, which would have been important for me to know.